# How to fetch phone number of a user by user id on telegram?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, telegram-api

I have a question that how to fetch the phone_number of a user by giving username or chat id. I know this question has been asked many times and everyone has said that there is no procedure for that but there is a website called [Callmebot](https://www.callmebot.com/get-phone-number-from-telegram-user-id/) which has a form on which the user can enter the username and phone number will be shown, if the user phone number is public. Please, let me know if there is a procedure for it. I've to implement this procedure in a ASP.NET Core Web Application.

I'll be very thankful for your act of kindness.

Regards,
Furrukh Nadeem

I've tried finding a way to solve this problem by doing literature review as well as seeing about more then 150 sites for this information and still I'm unable to find this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Telegram API method to retrieve a users public phone number is [`users.GetUsers`](https://corefork.telegram.org/method/users.getUsers) which will eventually return a [`user`](https://corefork.telegram.org/constructor/user) and their phone number if they are a contact or if their setting is public. Most people have their setting as private.

You can see an example of how to call a method in C# [here](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient#example-of-api-call).

Answer (score 0):

Fetching the Phone number given a username or user id. you can make sure of the telegram Bot API using the method **getChatMember**:

Use this method to get information about a member of a chat. The method is guaranteed to work for other users, only if the bot is an administrator in the chat. Returns a **ChatMember object** on success.

**Parameter**
user_id Integer Yes Unique identifier of the target user

kindly reference to the official BOT API : https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember